# mongoose: Cannot specify a custom index on `_id` for model name "SchemaName", MongoDB does not allow overwriting the default `_id` index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I just tried to custom `_id` in mongoose schema like this :

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        _id: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        ...
        ...
})
```

and get this message : `mongoose: Cannot specify a custom index on _id for model name "SchemaName", MongoDB does not allow overwriting the default _id index.`

The thing is, everything's fine. I can insert the data and select it like normal. Should I do something about that message?

Answer (score 29):

I think the error is appearing as you are trying to define `required:true` and `unqiue:true`, as `_id` will already have this in place, that is you cannot have `_id` to have non-unqiue value even if the condition from mongoose is not there and it is always required. Try dropping these two constraints and just setting the the `type:String` and this message should disappear

Comment: Thanks for writing here what you think. That made me realize something similar I was facing here, which helped me puting it together with another thing I recently learned and so I just wrote a new answer explaining it. And of course I gave your commend an upvote as well.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `_id: false` to the options `,{}` (second argument) does the trick:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    }, { _id: false })
```

That tells Mongo you don't want `_id` to be automatically created by Mongo/Mongoose.
Because you want to do it yourself, your own way.

In fact, if you are not using `_id`, you don't even need to mention it in the first argument. Only the second is important ({ _id: false }):

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    code:    { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    name:    { type: String, required: true },
    another: { type: Number, required: false },
  }, { _id: false })
```